# ¿Cómo funciona exactamente el login e interactúa con SESSION?

Tags: php, html, login, session

Bien, tengo esta página donde inicia sesión, ahora, aunque lo hace, yo quiero hacer que mi header cambie y en lugar de mostrar los botones de login y/sign-up, solo muestre el botón de log-out... Así como también el perfil del usuario para que haga modificaciones.

Yo soy un novato, comencé hace poco, aún no me termina de quedar claro que hace exactamente SESSION y cómo funciona, no tengo una idea clara en la mente, normalmente me guio de esta página https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_sessions.asp pero sigo sin poder encontrar una forma de lograr lo que quiero con esa información.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde un usuario debe ser capaz de comprar un asiento especifico en una sala de cine, pero antes de trabajar en ello tengo superar este obstáculo. No sé exactamente como googlear para conseguir lo que quiero o si la respuesta no esta tan clara, si tienen algún tutorial de cómo lograr esto en español o inglés, se los agradecería mucho.

> **PD:** Le pregunte a un amigo programador, y me sale con cosas como JWT... ¿No puedo hacer esto solo con PHP y HTML?

Este es el código de inicio de sesión (Mis códigos están llenos de comentarios, por que dejo notas para ayudarme a entender que es lo que estoy haciendo exactamente):

```
<?php session_start (); /*<--- que recuerde las variables que pusimos en la 
session*/
include 'dbh.inc.php';

$email2 = $_POST ['email2']; /*Creo una variable, que recibira con el metodo 
post, la variable que envie que se llama uid*/
$pwd = $_POST ['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email2' AND user_pwd = 
'$pwd'";  
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);


if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
/*Creamos una variable llamada row, que sera igual al resultado de la base 
de datos si es
que realmente recibimos un resultado de mi statement $sql (osea si realmente 
el e-mail y pwd
introducidos, hace match con la columna en horizontal de mi tabla. Pero ahora el signo de exclamación
me dice que si lo de arriba, NO PASO. Osea, si no tenemos resultado de la base de datos y el email y pwd
no hace match, entonces hara...Lo que sea que ponga en el codigo.*/ 
    {
    echo "Your username or password is incorrect!";
    }

else /* Esto se ejecutara si la busqueda hace match*/
{
/*"Estamos enviando una pieza de informacion en algo llamado session, que no se ha creado aun
    pero hay que asegurarse de que la session esta corriendo dentro de tu website, de otra manera
    no puedes ver esta informacion*/
    
$_SESSION ['id'] = $row['user_id']; /* dentro de los bracket, eligo el nombre de la variable session, alli lo llame ID el row eligo el user id por que es unico*/
header ("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

---

Y aquí lo compruebo en el header:

```
<?php
if (ISSET($_SESSION['id'])) 

    {echo $_SESSION['id'];}
else
    {echo "No tas logeado";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El $_SESSION lo que hace es guardar globalmente variables de sesión, en las cuales puedes alojar cosas como el nombre, el usuario, edad, apellidos de la persona que se logueo, todo lo que tengas en tu tabla de usuarios lo puedes guardar en las variables de sesión.

Ahora para hacer lo que tu dices de ocultar botones cuando estoy logueado y mostrar otros simplemente debes hacer condiciones con tu php, yo haría algo así:

1. En el momento en que mi usuario se loguee, después de hacer el `sesion_start()` inicial crearía una variable `$_SESSION['check'] = true;`
2. Con esta variable podría preguntar si el usuario esta logueado o no y así poder mostrar un contenido específico para cada caso

   ```
   if($_SESSION['check'] == true){
       /*Muestro contenido para usuarios logueasos*/
   }else{
       /*Muestro contenido para usuarios NO logueasos*/
   }
   ```

Tu caso también es válido:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
}else{
    echo "No tas logeado";
}
```

**Cabe aclarar que en todas las vistas donde quieras usar variables de sesión es obligatorio ejecutar primero `session_start();`**

Espero que te sirva, no dudes en preguntar si tienes más dudas !

Answer (score 0):

Las sesiones de PHP son completamente independientes de cualquier script, su función primaria es "mantener contacto" con el cliente (navegador); adicionalmente, te permite guardar variables que solo serán vigentes para esa conexión.

Entonces **session_start();** se requiere para iniciar esa conexión, creando (o recuperando) una ID de sesión para ese navegador y creando un espacio en el servidor para almacenar información, incluyendo las variables que tú vayas agregando.

Es con tus propias variables que controlas cosas en tu sitio y no todas tienen que ver con login, por ejemplo, un carrito de compras:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Esto debe ir antes de cualquier otra cosa

// Verificar si es el primer acceso para crear el carrito
if(!isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {
    $_SESSION['carrito'] = array();
}

// Agregar un producto que proviene desde un formulario
$_SESSION['carrito'][$_POST['id_producto']] = $_POST['cantidad'];
```

Resumen: Una cosa son las sesiones de PHP, que te facilitan herramientas para identificar el navegador y otra completamente diferente la identificación de usuarios en tu sitio, que son las que controlan el contenido a mostrar.